# The field is never read locally (catch-22)

Tags: android, eclipse

Is anybody face such problem?

Some fields marked with warning "The field is never read locally":

[image]

but when I suppress warning, it Eclipse starts claim that this is unnecessary:

[image]

As result, I can't get rid of warnings.

Eclipse SDK 3.6.2

**EDITED:**

The BlockBase class intended to be abstract. But adding `abstract` keyword to class and changing constructor visibility to `protected` doesn't change anything. I guess the real reason for this behavior that class market as private and thus compiler assumes that fields should be accessed from inside the class visibility area. It doesn't take into account, that these fields may be accessed from children, which have another visibility (`public class DataBlock extends BlockBase`).

I changed `BlockBase` visibility to `protected` and it **solved** the problem. I don't like to change it to public, because it will cause that `BlockBase` will be visible from outside the parent class, but changing visibility to `protected` doesn't change anything, because I parent class don't have inherited classes.

*But anyway, this compiler behavior is incorrect.*

[image]

**EDIT 2**

-or-

**HOW TO REPRODUCE THE PROBLEM**

*1. First file:*

```
public class testClass {

    private abstract class x
    {
        public int theProblem;
    }

    public class y extends x 
    {
    }

}
```

*2. Second file:*

```
public class anotherClass {

    public void accessToTheProblem()
    {
        testClass.y a = (new testClass()).new y();
        a.theProblem = 5;
        Log.i("TEST", "See, I can read theProblem: " + a.theProblem);
    }

}
```

Under Eclipse SDK 3.6.2 you will see that `theProblem` declaration market with Warning:

> The field is never read locally

Comment: Can't you just read them somewhere? I mean fake read them. In a constructor for example. It's not the most elegant solution, but oh well.

Comment: Put in getters and setters that are private if you don't want to use them?

Comment: Other than that. The warning is probably valid, so you shouldn't suppress it, but rather keep in mind the unused fields, and optimize them away or use them in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are intending `BlockBase` to be an `abstract` class like [`BaseAdapter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java)?

- If you don't plan on declaring a `BlockBase` object with `blockBase = new BlockBase(widget);` then add `abstract` to your class definition and remove your constructor. The compiler will understand that you plan to use these variables in a child class and it will remove the warnings.
- Otherwise the compiler is right, you should removes those variables because they will never be used in `BlockBase`. (If you plan to use them in `DataBlock`, then cut & paste them in there but they are meaningless to `BlockBase`.)

Comment: Your first suggestion is correct, but compiled doesn't understand my plan, as you expected. I edited question, please take a look at new screenshot.

Comment: The problem was solved by changing `BlockBase` class visibility to `protected`. It doesn't really change visibility, so it is acceptable solution, but I still can't say that compiler was right.

Comment: I'm glad you found _a_ solution. But I'm curious because I couldn't recreate your errors with the JDK set to 1.5 or 1.6. When `BlockBase` was `private abstract` did you try cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: I just added new edit to the question with illustration how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the compiler adds synthetic methods to emulate access to fields of nested/outer classes. Maybe that confuses the check here. You should be able to verify if this plays a role by setting the Eclipse compiler warnings preference "Access to non-accessible member of an enclosing type" to something higher than "Ignore".

Besides that, I suggest upgrading to 3.8 or 4.2, maybe we are speculating over a long fixed bug.